# Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator and $dim X=dim Y=n<\infty$. Show that ${\scr{R}}(T)=Y$ if and only if $T^{-1}$ does exist.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator and $\dim X=\dim Y=n<\infty$.  Show that ${\scr{R}}(T)=Y$ if and only if $T^{-1}$ exists.

I'm not sure how to start this one. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Hint: as with many questions involving "dimension", consider what happens to a basis.

Comment: Row rank = Column rank.

Comment: Or, look for the "rank nullity theorem"

Comment: I could swear I answered this question before...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How does the "rank nullity theorem" help?

Comment: $\text{null}(T) = 0 \iff T^{-1}$ exists

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So I want to show that $null(T)=0$ which implies $n=\dim X=\dim Y=rank(T)$. Which happens when ${\scr{R}}(T)=Y$?

Comment: @DesperateFluffy that's right

Answer (score 3):

A linear map $\;T:X\to Y\;,\;\;\dim X=\dim Y=n<\infty\;$ , is injective iff it is surjective.

This follows at once from the dimension theorem:

$$n=\dim X=\dim\ker T+\dim\,\text{Im}\,T$$

because:

$$T\;\;\text{is injective}\;\;\iff \dim\ker T=0\iff \dim\,\text{Im}\,T=n\iff T\;\;\text{is surjective}$$